# How is sum of the series in python

Tags: python

enter image description h[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy4g8.png)ere

S=1/x-1/(x+2x^2 )+1/(x+2x^2+3x^3 )-…

Using python in the sum of the first ten sentences of the following series(x=5)

Comment: Hi Abolfazl, Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please, consider checking [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `sympy`:

```
from sympy import symbols

x = symbols('x')

# ----------------------
r = 0
for i in range(1,12):
    v = 0
    for j in range(1,i):
        v += j*(x**j)
    if v!=0:
        r += (1/v)*(-1)**i
# ----------------------

res = r.subs({x:5}).evalf()
```

**r:**

[image]

---

**res:**

```
0.183848746978963
```

This can be solved even by using for loop and pass the x value directly.